# active_storage_drag_and_drop does not work on rails - Error: reject delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drag-and-drop, rubygems, rails-activestorage

I'm currently trying to implement the drag and drop feature to upload images using this: https://github.com/marinosoftware/active_storage_drag_and_drop

I followed all the steps and did all the gem install and included the require in my js and scss files. I have also gem install active storage before installing 'active_storage_drag_and_drop' gem.

It is working fine with the default active storage upload when is file_field:

```
                            <%= form_with(model: @work_order, local: true) do |form| %>
                                <%= form.file_field :image %>
                            <% end %>
```

However, when I changed to drag_and_drop_file_field instead:

```
                            <%= form_with(model: @work_order, local: true) do |form| %>
                                <%= form.drag_and_drop_file_field :image %>
                            <% end %>
```

The error:

**[ERROR] Exception ActionView::Template::Error: reject delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil**

Anyone have any idea on solving this issue? Thank you.

Version:
Rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32] and mysql2 (0.5.3)

Update 1:

Controller (for def new only):

```
class WorkOrdersController < ApplicationController
layout :resolve_layout, except: [:feedback, :completed_feedback, :sending_feedback]
before_action :normal_user
before_action {authorisation_for_modules("Work Orders Management")}

    def new

    initialise

    @work_order = WorkOrder.new
    @countries = Country.all
    @branches = Branch.all
    
end
```

Model:

```
    class WorkOrder < ApplicationRecord
#has_many :workorders, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :branch
has_one_attached :image 
end
```

Partial of full error:

```
  Rendered work_orders/new.html.erb within layouts/developers (334.9ms)
```

[ERROR] Exception ActionView::Template::Error: reject delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil, ["C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:278:in `rescue in method_missing'", "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:274:in` method_missing'", ......

Comment: Can you post the model and controller code

Comment: Also the full error please. When is this happening? Is this on submit?

Comment: @nolyoi Hi, the model and controller code has been posted. The partial of the full error is shown above as there are a lot more of the similar error lines occurring after method_missing'". The error occurred when I am entering the new.html. Thank you.